# Adding automatically standard structs or enums

Tags: ida, idapython

Is there any kind of IDAPython/IDC function, i.e. a programmatic method, that allows you to simulate this?

<kbd>Structures</kbd> -> <kbd>Insert</kbd> -> <kbd>Add standard structure</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modern counterparts of the functions from the original answer below are called:

- [`success add_default_til(string name);`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/174.shtml)
- [`long import_type(long idx, string type_name);`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/175.shtml)

---

I found the solution using **Til2Idb**

```
LoadTil("type_library_name") #example: mssdk
Til2Idb(-1, "YOUR_STRUCT_NAME_HERE") # example: IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER
```

The first parameter is used if you want it in a specific position of your structures list. "-1" means the end of the list.

Answer (score 2):

For enums you can use the `AddEnum(idx, name, flag)` function to create an enum inside an IDC script or Python script. This returns an `enum_id` which you can then use to create symbolic constant using `AddConstEx(enum_id, name, value, bmask)`.

After this you can then get the constant for the enum using the same `enum_id` `GetConstEx(enum_id, value, serial, bmask)`. This will return a `const_id` which can be used to set a repeatable comment for that value in the enum using `SetConstCmt(const_id, cmt, repeatable)`.

A short example of using this all together can be seen in this script I use;

```
def create_enum(enum_name, member_infos, offset, increment):
   return_id = AddEnum(-1, enum_name, 0x1100000);

    if return_id == BADADDR:
        error('Unable to create enum : %s' % enum_name)
        return return_id

    for member_info in member_infos:
        debug("Attempting to create enum member and comment : %s.%s -> %s" % (enum_name, member_info[0], member_info[1]))

        if AddConstEx(return_id, member_info[0], offset, -1) == 0:
            const_id = GetConstEx(return_id, offset, 0, -1)

            if const_id == -1:
                debug('Unable to get constant id for : %s.%s' % (enum_name, member_info[0]))

            else:
                if SetConstCmt(const_id, member_info[1], 1):
                    debug('Enum value created : %s.%s' % (enum_name, member_info[0]))

                else:
                    error('Enum value failed to have comment set : %s.%s' % (enum_name, member_info[0]))

                offset += increment
        else:
            error('Unable to create enum member : %s.%s' % (enum_name, member_info[0]))
            return -1

    info('Finished creating enum : %s' % enum_name)
    return return_id
```

This would be used as follows;

```
enum_to_create = [
    ('enum_1', 'enum1 comment'),
    ('enum_2', 'enum2 comment'),
    ('enum_3', 'enum3 comment'),
    ('enum_4', 'enum4 comment'),
    ('enum_5', 'enum5 comment')
]

create_enum('enum propername', enum_to_create, -0x8, 0x4)
```

As for the structures, it would appear you would go a similar route though using the structure commands like `AddStructEx(index, name, is_union)` and `SetStrucName(sid, name)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your post. The goal was to get a struct from a type library, meaning that we don't require to add the fields of a struct since we loaded it. Anyway, it would be useful for sure to anyone who wants to work with structs/enums :)!

Comment: Fair enough. Didn't realize you had the library available - I almost never do :)